# Refactoring an entire site without reinstalling

Tags: 7, migrations

I don't know if this a strange question ;)

I've a site, based on Drupal 7, core and all modules are updated and everything is managed with features (and obviously custom code for theme and some modules).

I've started it some years ago, now I've learned many things. There errors, too many modules, etc.

I would like to refactor it, preserving:

- users
- nodes (and so revisions), but refactoring some fields
- taxonomy and terms

Now, the question is: what do you suggest?
I see two ways:

- create a new drupal installation, with content types, taxonomies etc, and so migrate contents, terms, files and users from old site to the one. So I should have to create views, etc etc. Thid way could be simple because I've "only" to manage contents migration, but maybe I'll lose revisions
- work on a new branch (code on git), remove old features, recretating theme, removing everything that are not useful etc, with new configurations. This could be an hard work, but it preservs contents, etc.

Is there another way?

Thanks for suggestions :)

Comment: There isn't a fixed answer to this question. It depends on your site, content, available time/budget, plus lots of other things. It's not a great question for the format of this site because we don't have all the details needed to make the decision.

Comment: See https://www.drupal.org/node/1834016 for migration of revisions.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look. PS: no, budget, is my site ;)

Comment: In which case time is your budget.